# How can I use a newer CUDA Version with GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cuda, google-kubernetes-engine, nvidia

I'm currently trying to update one of our applications in our GKE cluster. The updated version of the application depends on CUDA 11.2. However, currently only version 11.0 (which is older than 1 year) is supported. Is there any way to force a newer CUDA version?

The standard process is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#cuda).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with CUDA 11.0, the CUDA toolkit supports enhanced version compatibility across minor releases.  GKE node images currently use Nvidia driver version `450.119.04` which is compatible with CUDA 11.x.

So it's possible to deploy an application built with CUDA 11.2 on GKE, but it depends on the 11.2 features you use.  See  https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#application-considerations.

Applications built with CUDA 11.0 can leverage all 11.0 features.

Comment: The linked documentation says "The latest supported CUDA version is 11.0 on both COS (1.18.6-gke.3504+) and Ubuntu (1.19.8-gke.1200+)." Is that wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer above to provide more detail.  GKE supports all features for CUDA 11.0 but it's possible to build 11.2 apps which use a limited set of new 11.2 features.

Comment: Due to bugs the 11.2 applications may not run if driver is 11.0, for example see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/70122. I can't understand why GKE has ancient version of CUDA 11.